# How to find point along arc in 3D given center, start & end points + radius + center angle?

Tags: math, geometry, angle, points

If I have three points, let's say:

```
start: (14.5, 10.1, 2.8)
end: (-12.3, 6.4, 7.7)
center: (0, 0, 0)
```

And the following additional information that has been determined:

```
Radius: 15
Center Angle: 109 degrees
Arc (from Pt A - Pt B): 29
```

How can I approach finding points along the arc between the starting and ending points?

Comment: When you say center, do you mean the midpoint of the arc or the center of the circle that the arc lies on? If the latter, then I believe you do not have enough info to define a single arc.

Comment: I actually mean the latter. I can compute the Midpoint, but this doesn't take into account the arc. I have the option of creating a parallelogram given those three points to simplify things. From there, I only need to find point #4, which will be the point directly opposite of the center (0, 0, 0). If I can find that point, I'll be able to programmatically draw a bezier curve. I only need 3 points in order to draw this curve, given the algorithm I have written.

Comment: Just some number-checking, but the start and end points are not the same distance from the "center" described. Additionally, neither one is radius 15 away. They are 15.85 and 17.89 away. You mention Bezier curves. Are you not making the arc from a circle?

Comment: I am well aware of the difference in distances between the start and ending locations. To better explain the task at hand: I'm plotting flight routes in 3D (e.g. from New York to London). The answer @fjf2002 provides looks good. Another solution I decided to try (although not as accurate) consists of building a parallelogram using the three points, then interpolating a Bezier path using the start & end points with that fourth point determined (if that makes sense). Do you forsee any problems with either solution off the top of your head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATE*: Vectors are marked with a °.

The normal *n°* of the plane *p* in which the circle (or the arc) lies is

```
n° = cross product of start°, end°
```

*p* contains all points *X°* satisfying the equation

```
dot product of n° and X° = 0
// ^^^ This is only for completeness, you needn't calculate it.
```

Now we want two orthogonal unit vectors *X°*, *Y°* lying in *p*:

```
X° = start° / norm(start°)
Y° = cross_prod(n°, start°) / norm(cross_prod(n°, start°))

(where norm(X°) is sqrt(x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2),
 and by dividing a vector V° by a scalar S I mean dividing each vector component by S:
 V° / S := (V°[1]/S, V°[2]/S, V°[3]/S)
```

)

In 2d coordinates, we could draw a circle with the parametrization

```
t -> 15*(cos(t), sin(t)) = 15*cos(t) * X° + 15*sin(t) * Y°
where X° = (1, 0) and Y° = (0, 1).
```

Now in 3d in plane *p*, having two orthogonal unit vectors *X°* and *Y°*, we can analogically do

```
t -> 15*cos(t) * X° + 15*sin(t) * Y°
where X°, Y° as defined before, and t goes from 0 to 109 degrees.
```

For *t=0*, we get point *start°*. For *t=109*, we **should** get *end°*. If that goes wrong, change *Y°* to *-Y°*. For t between 0 and 109, we get the arc between *start°* and *end°*.

Depending on your sin/cos implementation, you need to specify the angles in radians, not degrees.

Comment: I like this solution. I will give this a shot. I must ask an question that might be embarrassing, assuming that "start" and "n" are vectors: How do we divide vectors? Do you happen to have a reference to a tutorial?

Comment: I am curious what you are doing in that third block of code. I assume that `norm(start)` means you are normalizing the vector into unit length, otherwise you would be dividing a vector by a non-colinear vector, which doesn't work. Hence X and Y are scalars, not orthogonal unit vectors. Can you clarify this step a little?

Comment: I made the assumption that X & Y were vectors, too. Then I realized I had a problem: I don't know how to divide "vectors", or it that's even possible. I too need a bit of clarification.

Comment: OK, I have made it a bit clearer. Please ask if something is still not understandable.

Comment: I see now, though your terminology is a bit different from what I learned. When you say `norm(start°)` you actually mean the magnitude of `start°`. You are turning (correctly) `start°` and `(n° x start°)` into their normalized (i.e. unit length) versions. `normalize(start°) = start° / magnitude(start°)` should be the equation. And `X° = normalize(start°)`, of course.

Comment: You two are awesome! I'm going to code this real quick and see what's up. :-)

Comment: Well, this works! I wish I give partial credit to Maple for helping me make sense of the terminology. Now I must figure out how to specify the direction. The route of the curve isn't exactly being plotted as intended, but I'm in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks! Good luck in optimizing your program.

Comment: OK, so this doesn't work for me.  I think I'm confused by the notation for "X° = start° / norm(start°)"  My understanding was that X° is a vector, which is what I've implemented, but @Maple seems to be suggesting that it's a scalar, which would change the final line would take on an entirely different function.  Also, I don't really understand the notation "t -> ".  Are you saying that for each value of 't', apply this equation, and the result will be the 3D position you are after?

Comment: With "X° = start° / norm(start°)" I want to express a "division by a scalar". I know such a thing does not exist, but it's shorter than to write "X° = (1 / norm(start°)) * start°", a multiplication of a scalar with a vector. - "norm" means the magnitude of the vector. - Every ° in my notation above means it's a vector. - Notation "t ->" means function arrow notation, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics) . You can read it as "for each value of t in 0..109 degrees, calculate the term on the right".

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I was doing something stupid with the output of the function.  It works just fine now....